# Update Join 3 table CODEIGNITER 4

Tags: php, codeigniter-4

how to update data from 3 join table?
how is the flow to update data from 3 table joins

this is the table

user table

```
table 1
id_user
name
email
password
```

room table

```
table 2
id_room
name_room
status_room
price
```

rev table
join from table user and room

```
table 3
id_rev
id_room
id_user
facility
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What did you try so far?